# debugging browser related system freeze

Tags: arch-linux, freeze

I've been running this instance of arch for about 2 years.

I'm having a problem browsing the internet. Whenever I'm browsing my system suddenly starts freezing, it starts with the mouse getting slow.

It takes about 5 seconds to go from "starting to freeze" to "fully freezed". If I'm quick enough, I can switch to an terminal and "killall firefox" or "killall chrome" and everything goes right back to normal.

Most of the time I'm not quick enough and my only solution is to reboot(can't switch ttys, can't move mouse, can't anything).

Where should I start looking to find out who is causing this?

Comment: Small ram then a lots of swap? Use any system monitor.
Limit firefox ram usage with `ulimit` or `cgroups`.

Comment: @IporSircer, I have 6gb ram and no swap partition setup. How can I monitor it? Once it starts freezing, I can't do anything on the system(everything looks normal before freezing, both cpu and mem usage). I'll try ulimit and see if it changes things.

Comment: In your firefox browser url bar type `about:cache` and see where your caches are being saved.  Make sure you have plenty of disk space left there.  This is most likely your home directory so your probably still good.  Then if you want - have your cache stored in memory, since it seems you have enough.  In your browser bar type `about:config`, find `browser.cache.disk.enable` set it to `false`, `browser.cache.memory.enable` set it to `true`, `browser.cache.memory.capacity` set it to `-1`.  This at least can rule out some cache issues.